# Какая функция используется для вызова объекта класса в ООП на Python?

Tags: python, ооп

Существует функция **init**, которая вызывается при инициализации объекта класса

```py
class NewClass:
    def __init__(self):
        Действия, которые выполняются при инициализации объекта
```

У меня вопрос: существует ли функция, которая вызывается при вызове объекта?
Например, что я имею ввиду:

```py
class NewClass:
    def __названиеискомойфункции__(self):
        print("Функция была вызвана")
```

затем сделаем так:

```py
myobj1 = NewClass()
n1 = myobj1
n2 = myobj1
n3 = myobj1
```

Предполагаемый вывод:

```
Функция была вызвана
Функция была вызвана
Функция была вызвана
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

В Python есть специальный метод `__call__()`, который вызывается при вызове объекта как функции. Вот пример:

```
class NewClass:
    def __call__(self):
        print("Функция была вызвана")

myobj1 = NewClass()
n1 = myobj1()  # Вызывается метод __call__()
n2 = myobj1()  # Вызывается метод __call__()
n3 = myobj1()  # Вызывается метод __call__()
```

В этом примере метод `__call__()` будет вызываться при каждом обращении к объекту myobj1 как к функции, что приведет к ожидаемому выводу:

```
Функция была вызвана
Функция была вызвана
Функция была вызвана
```

Comment: Огромное спасибо!

Comment: Поставил Вам голос вверх и отметил решение как верное. Если не составит труда, поставьте, пожалуйста, на мой вопрос тоже голос вверх, заранее спасибо.